# What is the alternative to TwilioClient.Init() in Twilio.Api Version 3.4.1.0

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I want to send notification to Twilio and according to its official documentation TwilioClient.Init is used to initialize base class in latest versions.

[image]

[image]

Due to dependency on other dlls , I have to use Twilio.Api version 3.4.1.0 and there is no TwilioClient.Init method present in that old version.

[image]

So, what is the alternate method to TwilioClient.Init to Initialize?

Comment: FWIW, `TwilioClient.Init` **should not be used** anyway, because it mutates (global) `static` state. For example, in an ASP.NET Web Application, if two separate users (with their own Twilio Account SID) call the same controller action that uses `TwilioClient.Init` then one of them will get the other person's results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can instantiate the `TwilioRestClient` directly like this:

```cs
using Twilio;
string accountSid = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("...");
string authToken = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("...");
var client = new TwilioRestClient(accountSid, authToken);
```

Then for example to send a message pass the client into the resource method:

```cs
var message = MessageResource.Create(
    to: new PhoneNumber("+1..."),
    from: new PhoneNumber("+1..."),
    body: "Hello from C#",
    client: client);
```

Some documentation can be found in [Manual Client Initialization](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp-dotnet/usage-guide#manual-client-initialization).

The old versions are also on GitHub, I couldn't find 3.4.1, the closest tag I found was [3.2.3](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/tree/3.2.3).

But be careful, the version you're trying to use is deprecated and Twilio will no longer provides bug fixes for it!

Comment: Thanks @yvesoline, one last question, in the Twilio version I am using even NotificationResource class is missing , I confirmed from DotPeek.
So , what can be alternative to 

'var notification = NotificationResource.Create(
            body: "Hello Bob",
            identity: identity,
            pathServiceSid: "ISXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        );'